# Multiple has_one relations to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `User` and a `Shop` model (Rails 5.2) that should have multiple locations like `ship_location`, `bill_location`... How can I use the same `Location` multiple times for this?

The `User` and `Shop` model could look something like this

```
class User
  has_one :ship_location
  has_one :bill_location
end

class Shop
  has_one :ship_location
  has_one :bill_location
  has_one :contact_location
end
```

But I can't figure out how the `Location` model should look like. It should be as abstract as possible, so that I don't have to define a new relationship and/or models when the `Location` is used for another model.

I guess I have to use some sort of polymorphism:

```
class Location
  # location has owner_id and owner_type
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

But this doesn't work, because `user.ship_location` is ambiguous (it would look for `owner_type == "User"` and `owner_id == 1` but because there is also a `bill_location` with the same `owner_type` and `owner_id`, it doesn't work).

Do I need to create separate models for this, that share the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 => Take a column (let's say `location_type` Or any column which can make difference between `shipping location`,`billing location`, and `contact location`) in `Location` model

```
class User
  has_one :ship_location, -> { where("location_type = ?", 'ship') }, :class_name => "Location", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :bill_location, -> { where("location_type = ?", 'bill') }, :class_name => "Location", :dependent => :destroy
end

class Shop
  has_one :ship_location, -> { where("location_type = ?", 'ship') }, :class_name => "Location", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :bill_location, -> { where("location_type = ?", 'bill') }, :class_name => "Location", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :contact_location, -> { where("location_type = ?", 'contact') }, :class_name => "Location", :dependent => :destroy
end

class Location
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop
  # (has column 'location_type')
end
```

2 => While creating Location provide it's respective value (i.e `ship`,  `bill`, `contact`)
example ->
Let's say create `location` for shop for `loation_type` = `bill`

```
Location.create(location_type: 'ship', foo: 'bar' ...)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, didn't think of an extra column!

Comment: I think in the given code example, the third class should be `Location` not `Shop`. Will propose an edit.